# Making spring boot boostrap behind proxy

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to use Spring Boot using proxy.

I get the following message

```
$ spring init -l

Failed to retrieve help from service at 'https://start.spring.io'
(start.spring.io: unknown error)
```

I tried following

```
export http_proxy

export https_proxy

JAVA_OPTS settings
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using commons `HttpClient` and we build a default instance via [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html)

There are a bunch of system properties that are taken into account but I assume the following is the ones you're looking for:

- `http.proxyHost`
- `http.proxyPort`

Can you try that? If that does not work, please raise an issue on [the boot tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Behind corporate proxy using locally installed [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) proxy:

[image]

```
JAVA_OPTS 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```

Output:

```
$ spring init
Using service at https://start.spring.io
Content saved to 'demo.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> -Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080